# secure websocket (wss) on localhost

Tags: web, websocket, certificate

My Qt-based application uses an insecure websocket on localhost (ws://localhost:50050) in order to connect to a web browser. This works fine on most platforms, however, some web browsers (e.g. Safari) and anything on iOS require a secure websocket (wss://localhost:50050) and this in turn requires the app to contain a valid certificate. Since certificates for localhost cannot be issued the general recommendation is to use a self-signed certificate and I followed the instructions according to:

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost

and tested it with the standard Qt example app:

https://www.soundjack.eu/Downloads/sslechoserver.zip

However, this fails and now I wonder if current browser do not accept self-signed certificates anymore or if the the certificate must be created differently or if there is an alternative to this approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)